# On a grid, CheckboxModel does not work with grouping

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

The example configuration to reproduce this problem is at [sencha-fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bdt).

I am using ExtJS-4.2.1.883 here.

Essentially, when you collapse the top group, and try checking the row under AT&T, it doesn't select that row at all. If you check the console, the index of the selected row is shown as `-1`.

[image: Try Selecting This row]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two known grouping bugs in ExtJS 4.2.1, fixed in 4.2.2 ([EXTJS-10027](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264961-Grid-Grouping-Bug)) and 4.2.3 ([EXTJS-10043](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265078-Broken-contracts-of-getAt-indexOf-methods-of-the-Ext.grid.feature.Grouping)), respectively.

Comment: thanks a lot! the patch to bug#10027 seems to solve my problem. I don't have an idea if the other bug has any impact in my code yet.